# Extract closed captions VTT from stream using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, closed-captions, vtt

I can extract closed caption information from an mp4 file using ffmpeg v. 3.4.7 thus:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie="sample.mp4[out+subcc]" -map 0:1 -c:s webvtt /tmp/output.vtt
```

The file was obtained by capturing a live HLS stream containing closed captions.  I would like to extract the closed captions directly from the stream, instead after storing the video in a file.  I've tried various things, including:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie="http://example.com/stream.m3u8[out+subcc]" -map 0:0 -c:s webvtt /tmp/output.vtt
```

But the movie filter does not recognize the URL, even though the [ffmpeg filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#movie-1) says that the file name for the movie filter is "not necessarily a file; it can also be a device or a stream accessed through some protocol":

> [Parsed_movie_0 @ 0x264ad80] Failed to avformat_open_input 'http'
> [lavfi @ 0x2647e80] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'http://example.com/stream.m3u8'
> movie=http://example.com/stream.m3u8[out+subcc]: No such file or directory

When I capture the video form the stream like this:

```
ffmpeg -i http://example.com/stream.m3u8 /tmp/output.mp4
```

ffmpeg reports that the stream does contain closed captions (which is where the captured video file sample.mp4 got them):

> Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 480x270 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 14.99 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc

Is it possible to do this?  Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

movie filter can accept URLs you just need to escape ":"
According to https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping

this command should work

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i movie="http\\\://example.com/stream.m3u8[out+subcc]" -map 0:0 -c:s webvtt /tmp/output.vtt`

Comment: Just tested this and it works.  Thank you very much!